# How to convert smalldatime GMT Format?

Tags: c#, asp.net

pubdate is smalldatetime.

```
new XElement("pubDate", FormatPubDate(Convert.ToDateTime(rDetail.PubDate)))
    ///******************
private static string FormatPubDate(DateTime pubDate)
{
    //string Format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    string _tmpdate = pubDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("R");
    return pubDate.ToString(_tmpdate);
}
```

my format is ri, 14 Jan 2011 08:34:00 G1T 
but i want to this format
Mon, 17 Jan 2011 10:16:12 GMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you're asking, as the "R" format generates the form you said you're asking for.  That is `ToString("R")` will give `Mon, 17 Jan 2011 10:16:12 GMT`.

Take a look at the documentation for [ToString(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) for a list of standard date/time format strings and sample outputs.

If there's not a standard format string that meets your needs, then you can construct your own [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).